# CUDA, find out the number of registers in the kernel at runtime

Tags: cuda

how can I find out the number of registers cuda kernel is using during run time?
I know how to find out information during the compilation, but I do not want to hardcode numbers in

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with CUDA 2.x to get the information at run time.  Looking at the documentation for the new 3.0 beta, it seems that [cudaFuncGetAttributes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EXECUTION.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1g19b1696533069c03f646e2ce2beacc00) will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the one you see in the compilations are the one that are going to be used at runtime, or at least the maximum number of registers used at runtime.

Comment: This is likely false; see talonmies answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483321/what-kind-of-variables-consume-registers-in-cuda