# What kind of variables consume registers in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

```
__global__ void add( int *c, const int* a, const int* b )
{
    int x = blockIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y;
    int offset = x + y * gridDim.x;
    c[offset] = a[offset] + b[offset];
}
```

In the above example, I guess `x`, `y`, `offset` are saved in registers while

- **nvcc -Xptxas -v** gives `4 registers, 24+16 bytes smem`
- **profiler** shows 4 registers
- and the head of **ptx** file:

  ```
  .reg .u16 %rh<4>;
  .reg .u32 %r<9>;    
  .reg .u64 %rd<10>;  
  .loc    15  21  0   

  $LDWbegin__Z3addPiPKiS1_:   
  .loc    15  26  0
  ```

Can anyone clarify the usage of registers? In Fermi, the maximum number of registers is 63 for each thread. In my program I want to test the case when a kernel consumes too many registers (so variables may have to be stored in local memory automatically and thus leads to performance decrease). Then at this point I can split one kernel into two so that each thread has enough registers. Assume that the SM resources are sufficient for concurrent kernels.

I'm not sure if I am right.

Comment: Is your question "Why does this code use 4 registers instead of 3?" If so, the answer is this: In order to add `a[offset]` and `b[offset]`, both of those values must be fetched. It has to store whichever one it fetched first someplace while it's fetching the other. So one more register is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so can we say intermediate variables will be saved in registers?

Comment: When necessary, yes. It's not always easy to tell when that's necessary and it can even vary based on the hardware target.

Comment: Got it :-P     since the register usage is sophisticated, is there a way to find the boundary of register usage for a kernel, since I wish to test the case of Register Spilling, but when I try to declare more variables, the register usage remains the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The register allocation in PTX is completely irrelevant to the final register consumption of the kernel. PTX is only an intermediate representation of the final machine code and uses [static single assignment form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), meaning that each register in PTX is only used once. A piece of PTX with hundreds of registers can compile into a kernel with only a few registers.

Register assignment is done by `ptxas` as a completely standalone compilation pass (either statically or just-in-time by the driver, or both) and it can perform a lot of code reordering and optimisations on the input PTX to improve throughput and conserve registers, meaning that there is little or no relationship between the variables in the original C or registers in PTX and the final register count of the assembled kernel.

`nvcc` does provide some ways to influence the register allocation behaviour of the assembler. You have `__launch_bounds__` to provide heuristic hints to the compiler which can influence register allocation, and the compiler/assembler takes the `-maxrregcount` argument (at the potential expense of register spilling to local memory, which can lower performance). The volatile keyword used to make a difference to older versions of the nvopen64 based compiler and could influence the local memory spill behaviour. But you can't arbitrarily control or steer register allocation in the original C code or PTX assembly language code.

Comment: Thanks a lot,talonmies. so I guess there is nothing we can do about the register usage control in our kernel? The compiler always does a lot.

Comment: You have `__launch_bounds__` to provide heuristic hints to the compiler which can influence register allocation, and the compiler/assembler takes the `-maxrregcount` argument. The `volatile` keyword used to make a difference to older versions of the nvopen64 compiler and could influence the local memory spill behaviour. But you can't arbitrarily control or steer register allocation in the original C code.