# How to design for reduced register usage in Numba Cuda Kernels?

Tags: python, cuda, numba, register-allocation

UPDATE:  The original question below remains a good quesiton asking about general design principles for GPU programming in Numba and it is not quite the same as predicting register usage.  I have also since discovered there's no need to predict register usage since there is an undocumented command in Numba that tells you the register usage exactly.  THis can allow one by trial an error to reduce register use, but converting that to general intuition and strategies for register use what this question is asking.  The links added before this question claiming answers contian incorrect information that don't answer this question.  Those links and the comments on this quesiton simply claim, completely incorrectly, that register use can't be determined from numba.  This is absolutely incorrect, there is a not-yet-documented private method numba supplies to do exactly that.  This question isn't asking that.  It's asking how one strategically designs up front to minimize register use.

If a kernel uses more than 64 registers then on many cuda devices one can't use the maximum number of available threads.  I find that my code also seems to use way more registers than I would guess from scanning it visually for the number of intermediate results.  Even loops add lots to the register count.

So how can one see what lines of code are the culprits in using registers?

I'd settle for some rules of thumb or even better if there was a way to look at the numba IR available in the kernel.inspect_types() output.

***IS there some equivalence between the $ sigil variables in the Numba IR code and registers?***

I realize I can get get the total register count for a kernel by looking at the ._func.info and _.fun.get().attr and that's helpful.  But it doesn't tell you what aspect in your code is causing the number of registers to balloon.

So I want a way to either be able to guess better or actually see it in the Numba IR.

Any insights?

FOr concreteness, here is a trivial example of this someone posted:
https://gist.github.com/sklam/0e750e0dea7571c68e94d99006ae8533

When I say rules of thumb I am thinking that maybe they might look like this

1. Add one for every fetch from global memory not going into shared
   memory
2. add one for every binary operator like + or *
3. Add one for every input variable name (e.g. a pointer to global)
4. add one for every local variable.

But In practice I see more register's used than that would account for. And I also see the register count go up quite a lot when I include a loop or an if-statement.  Thus I know I'm not doing it right.

**Bottom line** *How can I skillfully reduce register counts?* 
I realize that optimizing compilers might be doing tricks to re-order code or choose when to make a variable a register or main memory, but still I think there ought to be rule one can follow to try to reduce register usage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11483321/681865

Comment: @talonmies  Thanks for the link, but that link is about using c-cuda and nvcc, not Numba or the Numba-IR so I don't think it applies to my question.  If there is a way it does apply to my question then I need help understanding how I get this output in this for.  For example, alternatives to the Numba-IR are the kernel.inspect_llvm() kernel.inspect_asm() outputs.  I did try those hoping to see the register usage correspondence but I didn't see it there either.  Perhaps an example of how one gets from the numba-python to this register usage would help.

Comment: <continued..>  Alternatively perhaps you were referring to the part of the answer in that link that says the PTX register usage does not correspond to the actual register usage.  This also doesn't make sense to me. First, the register usage reported by kernel._func.get().attr appears correct.  Second, as my original question noted I'm unsure if the Numba_IT, llvm, or asm output shows where the registers are being consumed.  Perhaps you are saying they can't.  And yet the Numba reported register count does look correct, so it seems like the info has to be available to Numba somehow. Thanks

Comment: It applies to your question. Numba IR is compiled to LLVM IR and then to PTX, then assembled. Numba relies on the same compiler infrastructure as nvcc (which is *not* a compiler). You can't estimate registers for Numba IR for the same reason you can't estimate registers from PTX (which is the exact answer I linked to).

Comment: @talonmies.  Thank you much for that clarification.  I did not realize that the LLVM IR was before the PTX layer so now that makes sense. However, I'd like to get your keen opinion of the kernel._func.get().attr return value in numba.  Notably, the .regs and .max_threads values.  the latter seems to be perfectly accurate and nearly equal to 1024/regs !  So it must be getting the reg count right somehow.  Perhaps this comes from the final layer of compilation and too distant from the code to tell how the regs are used.  But unexplained is the reg-count is more than the numba IR $-var count

Comment: <continued..>  I say unexplained because when I read your nice explanation, I learned that the IR representations don't recycle  to optimize the register count, and hence their register counts aren't coupled well to the final reg count. so it's an upper bound. But what I see is more register usage sometimes than my hand count of the number of $-vars in the numba IR.  That seems inconsistent.  It maybe I'm wrongly assuming the $-vars are every place where a register *might* be needed.  If wrong, how *do* I spot potential registers in the Numba or llvm or asm IR?  That would be useful to know.

Comment: You are wasting your time on this. In general, all of these IR stages are static single assignment form. There is no reuse of registers and no relation to final machine code. The CUDA assembler (`ptxas`) does a lot of optimization, idiom analysis and instruction interleaving to optimize memory and instruction throughput. There is literally no a priori heuristics from high level code like NUMBA IR or PTX that will let you guess a register count. You are going to have to accept that NUMBA for CUDA is an unfinished implementation that doesn't expose everything the native toolchain does

Comment: @talonmies  I note that in the post you linked to the same obeservation can be made.  THere, the PTX showed 3 registered needed, but the final compilation used 4 registers.  Which is more not less.  I realize that 3 versus 4 is not important, I'm just making the point that it's weird the register count would rise higher than the PTX.  It matters when one has say 50 $-vars in the numba-IR but the reported register count is  over 64.  Then you run out of resources and have to dial back the block size (which is annoying and less efficient).  Hence the desire to translate IR to an upper bound.

Comment: I can show you examples with hundreds of PTX registers than compile to less than 10 registers in the final assembled code. There are no generalizations. The jit interface exposes `max_registers` which will get to ptxas. Use it. If you need more control or information, raise a feature request with the developers

Comment: @talonmies Just to be clear, I agree that it's very reasonable to expect the PTX reg count to be higher than the final assembled code reg count.  That direction makes perfect sense.  What I'm saying is the opposite happens and did so in the other post too.  the reg count was *higher* not lower in the final assm.  Perhaps it's this instruction interleaving that bloats the register count.  I could believe that even if I can't quite see why. Anyhow, it seems like reducing regs in the PTX should tend to reduce regs in assm, so would be a useful heuristic.  Is that wrong?

Comment: @talonmies Also, by the way, in numba.cuda the max_registers setting is broken!  it doesn't do anything right now.  There's a bug report filed.  In fact that was how I got onto this whole thing.  I was trying to use that to hint how to improve thread counts and it wasn't working.  Hopefully it will be fixed.  But it's still not the same as improving the code itself so it naturally needs fewer registers. Hence the desire for *upper bounding*  register usage of any given code design.  Are those $-vars in the numba IR the PTX registers?  If so thats a heuristic  for less resource intensive code.

Comment: No they are not PTX registers. They are SSA variables. And on the register consumption question, the CUDA ABI itself consumes registers. A null PTX function will have a register footprint of 3 or 4 registers. And all CUDA registers are 32 bit. So some parameters, like pointers, consume two registers, even if the PTX or prior SSA source only has one. There are all sorts of things that you can't know at the front end of the toolchain.